# error: /SourceCache/GoogleMobileMaps_Sim/GoogleMobileMaps-263.5/googlenav/mac/Loader.mm:231 server returned error: 403

Tags: iphone

I'm working as iphone developer. i've a problem that in my mapview when ever I want to show location in google map it show me error: /SourceCache/GoogleMobileMaps_Sim/GoogleMobileMaps-263.5/googlenav/mac/Loader.mm:231 server returned error: 403 with square box screen. I got this question in stack overflow but that answer is not working for me. please some one help me.

Comment: "I got this question" .... what question?

Comment: I would put some code in the question showing what you have attempted.

Comment: Time is up ... bored now. Bye

Comment: actually i want to show some location in google mapview but instead of map it show only square boxes.with pin what I put. and in my nslog it show error:   /SourceCache/GoogleMobileMaps_Sim/GoogleMobileMaps-263.5/googlenav/mac/Loader.mm:231 server returned error: 403. one month before the same code was working perfectly but now what going wrong i do not understand. please some one help  me

Answer (score 1):

I believe Google has a strict rate limit on how many lookups can be initiated from an IP address, and if that rate (which is about 1 every 5-6 seconds) is exceeded even for a few lookups, then the IP address can be blocked for a number of hours.

This *may* be your problem.  Try using the application from another IP address (different wifi hotspot).  This would explain a 403 Error (which means Forbidden, not that there is a problem necessarily).

Comment: thanks for ur response but i'm not getting according to your answer. please give me some other solution if you have. thanks

Comment: @sandy - please follow my comment before that you should put some more detail in your question.  All you are giving us is an error message - no detail of what you are doing at all, no code, what you have tried etc.  I'm not saying I will be able to help, but you are getting no replies to this question because you are not helping

Comment: I'm sorry  iandotkelly, I was in my native home.Actualy want to show some location from my apps. in my previous company it is working fine. but it not working. as u told i change my IP address but still I'm facing problem

Comment: @sandy - and you are still not offering to show us some code?  You are just repeating "it used to work and now I am getting a 403 error".  This question is now very old.  I suggest you ask it again - but this time I suggest giving a *LOT* more detail.